# mount fails from spawned process

Tags: linux, init, mount

I want to start a process that uses a USB hard drive once it gets inserted.
Since UDEV rules specifically mentions not to run long-time processes from RUN command, I send a FIFO message to my service which then opens the relevant process.

So the flow goes like this:
UDEV > runs action process > sends FIFO message to service > service gets message > runs the process who works with the HDD (aka HDD-PROCESS).

If I run my service from shell-1 and run 'action process' (the one that UDEV runs) from shell-2 everything works (including when trying it with udev).
But in deployment, the service is spawned from init, and when it does, the `mount` command fails saying "No such device".

I then detached "HDD-PROCESS" with `fork` and `setsid`, but that didn't help either.

from inittab:

```
::respawn:/opt/spwn_frm_init
```

`ps` relevant output:

```
PID    PPID  PGID  SID  COMM             ARGS
31112     1 31112 31112 spwn_frm_init    /bin/sh /opt/spwn_frm_init
31113 31112 31112 31112 runSvc           /bin/sh /app/sys/runSvc
31114 31113 31112 31112 python           python /app/sys/mainSvc.py
24064     1 24064 24064 python           /usr/bin/python /app/sys/hdd_proc.py sdb1
```

- everything runs under root (`ps` shows that too, I omitted that to save screen space).

So in short: when I run `/opt/spwn_frm_init` from shell, everything works. when I kill it and let it re-spawn from inittab, it doesn't and `mount` fails with error above.

**UPDATE:**
There is no problem when trying to `mount` an ext3 drive, but only on the NTFS one (using ntfs-3g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
One of the differences between spawned process and another one who runs from shell is the environment variables which usually should be a problem when all I want is to call `mount`.
But when I noticed the problem happens only with the `NTFS` drive, it suddenly occurred to me that `mount` might need to call `ntfs-3g` so it worth checking if the second is accessible in the `PATH` variable.

`which ntfs-3g` led to `/usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g` which was mentioned in the default shell `PATH` but not in the one spawned from init.

To solve it, I added this `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` in the "HDD-PROCESS" and `mount` began to work :)

A better error message in `mount` could have saved a lot of time here...